# Implementation of Prolog extension handling temporal operators

Tags: prolog, logic, temporal

I am looking for implementation of Prolog extension which handles temporal logic operators. Is there any info about this ? 
As temporal logic has been a significant part of logic, I am sure that there must have been discussions about this with respect to prototype or implementation.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to take a look at [Etalis](http://code.google.com/p/etalis/). If it turns out to be overkill (I'm sorry I never really delved inside too much), and you're using SWI-Prolog, see if pack [Julian](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=julian) could be a better fit. It's nicely integrated with [CLP(FD)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd) library and will leave you full freedom about the semantics of your operators. Of course, it's a 'lower level' approach...

Answer (score 3):

I would start with Carlo's suggestions. But if you're looking only for basic temporal logic operators, the Logtalk library includes an implementation for basic temporal interval relations:

https://logtalk.org/docs/interval_0.html

You can use Logtalk as an extension to most Prolog implementations.